# Is there a way of binding a Java object in JAXP or Xalan XSLT scope?

Tags: java, xslt, xalan, jaxp

Xalan-J lets us [create and manipulate java objects](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ext-func-calls) using it's extension mechanism. What I want to do is to pass an already created object from Java (from the JVM that invokes Xalan) and then manipulate this object from xslt.

For example, I would want to do something like this:

```
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl));
HashMap mymap = ...
transformer.setParameter("MapToBeManipulatedByXsl", mymap);
transformer.transform(...)
String fromXSL = mymap.get("some-key-added-by-xsl");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite the same level of integration that you get with Xalan-J, but by far the simplest way of manipulating Java objects with XSL that I've dealt with was to use JAXB to turn the objects to/from XML.

JAXB lets you annotate your Java objects with tags specifying how you want them to appear in their equivalent XML document, then does all the work of translating Java-to-XML and XML-to-Java. Take your Java object, run it through JAXB, run your XSL over it, then run it back through JAXB to get the Java object back.

The benefits of this technique include:

- You are not tied to a particular XSL environment or interpreter. Your
  XSL only operates on XML.
- The translation from Java to XML and back again is a core part of the JRE, 
  and does not require any third party libraries
- You can unit test your XSLs independently of the Java
  application environment, by passing in text files and verifying the
  output

Comment: though not exactly I was looking for but still a nice idea. Thanks